# Python - evaluate a function with for

Tags: python, numpy

I want to evaluate discrete points of a function for each value of a given array (named `wl`). So far I have:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy

#wl is a defined list
a=1
b=3934.3
c=0.2885
for x in (wl):
    G[x]=a*exp(-(wl(x)-b)^2/c^2)
```

but I get the error `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`. What I need is a second list named `G` whose values correspond to the evaluated function at each value in the list `wl`.

What does this error mean? Should I somehow define `G` before?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not actually defined as a list. This is your problem: `wl(x)` What is your intent?

Comment: Please supply the whole traceback, not just the error.

Comment: You say `wl` is a list, but you're calling it as though it were a function. Which is what the error says.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking it in a too complicated way and just mean: G = a*exp(-(wl-b)^2/c^2) ? If wl is a numpy array, that'll give you the gaussian function. No need for any loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
G=numpy.exp(-(wl-b)**2/c**2)*a
```

I think would work ... since you can often drop in whole numpy arrays' like they were a single value and get back a new array of calculated values

(changed `^` to `**` since I think you want power not bitwise XOR)

you can see this behavior like so

```
t1 = numpy.array([1,2,3])
print t1 - 1
print t1 * 2
print t1 ^ 2
print (t1^2)*2
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know they can be treated like this. However I get an error in relation with another function: `TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types`.

Comment: ^ is XOR not power if you want power use `**` since your list is floating point numbers it doesnt know how to XOR <float> against a <int> (or something like that at least... )

Answer (score 0):

If `wl` is a list (or `numpy.ndarray`) you can't do `wl(x)`.

Probably you need `x` in place of `wl(x)` in `a*exp(-( wl(x)-b )^2 / c^2)`